# Sorting a list in Python containing tuples with Selection Sort

Tags: python, sorting, selection

I would like to sort the following list using selection sort:

```
list1 = [(1,2,3),(3,6,4),(4,7,9)]
```

How can I sort the above by the second element of each tuple (2,6,7) ?

I have the following code for a normal selection sort, but I do now know how to do it with tuples.

```
def selection_sort(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        mini = min(list[i:])
        min_index = list[i:].index(mini)
        list[i + min_index] = list[i] 
        list[i] = mini
```

Comment: Note that `mini` now needs to be the item in `list` (**don't name your own variable `list`**) with the smallest second element - see [the docs on `min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)

Comment: May I ask why I shouldn't have?

Comment: where are the tuples?

Comment: Sorry, that was an typing error, its fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `min` to use the second element for comparisons:

```
mini = min(list[i:], key=lambda l: l[1])
```

Btw, it's bad to call your variable `list` because then you can't use Python's own `list` anymore and because you're confusing everyone. Also, you didn't even make it a list but a tuple, preventing the in-place sorting that you're trying.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the brackets were a mistake on my part.

Comment: if you feel the strong urge to name a variable `list`, go with either `l` or `list_` instead.